# Как выполнить действие при установке своего приложения

Tags: c#, visual-studio, install, windowsinstaller

Мне необходимо выполнять определённые действия при установке моего приложения и сразу после неё. Для этого я в свой проект добавил новый компонент installer class, создал в нём метод Installer_AfterInstall, в его же дизайнере подписался на событие:

```
private void InitializeComponent ( )
    {
        //components = new System.ComponentModel.Container ( );

        this.AfterInstall += new System.Configuration.Install.InstallEventHandler ( this.Installer_AfterInstall );
    }
```

Пересобрал проект, пересобрал его установщик, запускаю установщик, установка происходит нормально, но код в Installer_AfterInstall не выполнился. Удили весь код из тела этого метода, оставил только создание файла просто для эксперимента:

```
private void Installer_AfterInstall ( object sender, InstallEventArgs e )
    {
        try
        {
            System.IO.File.Create ( @"D:\Testblabla.txt" );
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

Ноль реакции. Права точно есть, установщик я запускаю с правами администратора. Установка проходит, файл не появляется. Я забыл что-то ещё сделать? Что мне следует проверить?

Comment: _в свой проект добавил_ - в инсталлятор добавил или в устанавливаемое приложение?

Comment: В устанавливаемое приложение.